# Reactive way to process a zipped CSV file with CSVReader

Tags: java, project-reactor, csvreader

This is a follow-up question to this:
[How to convert a Flux to a Mono with multiple counters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76045906/how-to-convert-a-flux-to-a-mono-with-multiple-counters)

I found out that the problem lies with the CSVReader in this context. For some reason it does not properly create a `Flux` from it to be processed.

This doesn't work:

```
@Test
void testCsvReader() {
    StepVerifier.create(csvFlux()).verifyComplete();
}

@SneakyThrows
Mono<Void> csvFlux() {
var failure = new AtomicInteger();
var filtered = new ArrayList<String>();
var is = new ByteArrayInputStream(createZipContent(CSV_FILE_NAME, TEST_CSV.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
var reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new ZipInputStream(is)))) {
return Flux.fromIterable(reader)
        .flatMap(this::ean)
        .filter(ean -> filter(ean, filtered))
        .onErrorContinue((ex, integer) -> failure.getAndIncrement())
        .collectList()
        .flatMap(list -> print(list.size(), failure, filtered));
}

Mono<String> ean(final String[] record) {
    System.out.println("processing: " + Arrays.toString(record));
    var ean = record[1];
    if ("product1".equals(ean)) {
      return Mono.just(ean);
    }
    return Mono.error(RuntimeException::new);
}

boolean filter(final String ean, final List<String> filtered) {
    if ("product2".equals(ean)) {
      filtered.add(ean);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}

Mono<Void> print(final int success, final AtomicInteger errorCount, final List<String> filtered) {
    System.out.println("success:" + success + "; failure:" + errorCount + "; filter: " + filtered);
    return Mono.empty();
}
```

But if I create the CSV like this, it works:

```
Mono<Void> run() {
    var csv = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    csv.add(new String[] {"1234", "product1", "100"});
    csv.add(new String[] {"1234", "product2", "200"});
    csv.add(new String[] {"1234", "product3", "300"});
    var failure = new AtomicInteger();
    var filtered = new ArrayList<String>();
      return Flux.fromIterable(csv)
              .flatMap(this::ean)
              .filter(ean -> filter(ean, filtered))
              .onErrorContinue((ex, integer) -> failure.getAndIncrement())
              .collectList()
              .flatMap(list -> print(list.size(), failure, filtered));
}
```

Could it be because we have CSV Files within a ZIP file and thus the CSVReader get's confused?

**EDIT:**
It is indeed because we pass in a `ZipInputStream` to the `CSVReader`. If I pass in normal `InputStream` of a CSV it works. This begs the question: Why does it work if I directly subscribe to the `Flux` but not if I use `collectList()`?

Comment: Can you tell more about "does not properly create a Flux"? What do you mean? Do you have a compiler error? or some kind of a runtime exception?

Comment: I finally confirmed it is because the CSV is part of a ZIP file and if we pass in the InputStream from the ZIP file, the CSVReader does not provide items for the Flux unless you directly subscribe or block it. So what I mean with it, the List will always be empty and it ends up in the last flatMap with 0, 0 and an empty List.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, with the help of some other SO posts, each bringing a piece of the puzzle:

```
@SneakyThrows
Mono<Void> run() {
  var failure = new AtomicInteger();
  var filtered = new ArrayList<String>();
  var is = getSequenceInputStream(createZipContent(TEST_FEED_CSV_FILE_NAME, TEST_CSV.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
  return Flux.<CSVReader>generate(sink -> extractZipEntry(is, sink))
      .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)
      .flatMap(this::ean)
      .filter(ean -> filter(ean, filtered))
      .onErrorContinue((ex, integer) -> failure.getAndIncrement()).collectList()
      .flatMap(list -> print(list.size(), failure, filtered));
}

void extractZipEntry(InputStream is, SynchronousSink<CSVReader> sink) {
  var zis = new ZipInputStream(is);
  try {
    var zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
    if (zipEntry == null) {
      sink.complete();
    } else {
      var reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(zis));
      reader.readNextSilently();
      sink.next(reader);
    }
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    sink.error(new RuntimeException(ex));
  }
}
```